# jQuery "fighting" against the scroll after smooth scroll effect clicking a link

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

I applied a code on my page to get a smooth scrolling to specific divs when the user click a menu item (anchor tags). After clicking the nav menu the page runs to the place, as desired. The problem is that it "sticks" the page at that place and jquery prevent us to scroll as normal to somewhere else.

I put the href and id's on my divs, as I said the scrolling effect is working, the only weird thing is that after it goes to the desired place, jquery prevents me to scroll up or down.

Here's the JS code:

```
$("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
```

Does someone have an idea why is that happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but here is a solution to your problem. You need jQuery `.stop()` function to stop the animation if a user uses the scrollbar.

```
$(window).bind("mousewheel", function() {
$("html, body").stop();
});
```